# Package-wide Global Variable

Tags: python-3.x, global-variables

I have the simple module:

```
# first.py
def f(z): 
    return eval(z)
```

and another module:

```
# mod.py
from first import *
x = 20
print(eval("x+1"))
print(f("x"))
```

now if we run

```
bash$ python3 mod.py
```

it will print

```
21
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mod.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(f("x"))
  File "/Users/chekadsarami/Documents/Python Projects/vPrint/first.py", line 2, in f
    return eval(z)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

It is because when *print(f("x"))* is executed, it goes to the module first.py and variable *x* goes out of scope.

Is there a way to avoid that and have variable x pass from one module ( mod) to another ( first)?

Any help would be appreciated.

CS

Comment: Yes. Simply call `f(x)` and get rid of `eval` alltogether - its dangerous to use.

Comment: I need to use eval! Therefore it is not impossible! I don't know why someone has voted negative for this question?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use **eval**()!! It's dangerous to use and will break your program.

Except that, try this:

***first.py***

```
def f(z): 
    return z
```

***mod.py***

```
from first import f
x = 20
print(eval("x+1"))
print(f(x+1))
```

Comment: I am sorry. I need to have eval() there for my application. I thought that this is not possible in Python.